# Django REST framework custom model permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to create django custom permission for a model based on user roles.

Organization Model:

```
class Organization_Model(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=False, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField()
```

Organization Roles:

```
class Organization_Roles_Model(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=False, editable=False)
    Name = models.CharField()
```

Organization Members:

```
class Organization_Members_Model(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=False, editable=False)
    Organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization_Model)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Role = models.ForeignKey(Organization_Roles_Model)
```

Organization Groups:

```
class Organization_AssetsGroups_Model(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=False, editable=False)
    Organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization_Model)
    Name = models.CharField()
```

Custom Permissions:

```
class isOrgOwnerOrAdmin(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, object):
        User = request.user
        Roles = Organization_Roles_Model.objects.filter(Name__in=['Owner', 'Admin'])
        OrgsMember = [OrgID for OrgID in Organization_Members_Model.objects.filter(User=User, Role__in=Roles).values_list('Organization', flat=True)]
        if object.id in OrgsMember:
            return True
```

I've created this permission that can be applied only for Organization_Model, but I want to create a permission that can be applied to all objects that are linked to Organization_Model based on their roles in the organization. How can I achieve this easily without creating a permissions for each object that is related to Organization_Model?

Comment: You should override ```has_permission(self, request, view)``` instead of ```has_object_permission``` and starting from the ```request.user``` you should retrieve his/her role.

Comment: If I override has_permission works great for one organization but I I have multiple organizations.

Comment: Can you provide an example because i am not sure what you exactly want ?

Comment: I have organization one with members (admin - can perform all actions and member - read only) and second organization with different members. I want to provide access to each member if it part of his organization. For example Member1 that is part of Organization1 can access only info from Organization1 and Member2 that is part of Organization2 can access only organization2.

Comment: Please add the view matching what you want to achieve.

Comment: ```  class Organization_Members_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization_Members_Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Organization_Members_Serializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete'] # List, Update, Create, Delete  ```   Each member should see members only from their organization

Comment: ```queryset = Organization_Members_Model.objects.filter(Organization=self.request.user.Organization_Members_Model__Organization)``` ?